# Profile Deployment Error: Unknown user permission CanAccessCE

Tags: permissions, profile, deployment-error, system-permissions

We are getting an error when trying to deploy code of our project into another sandbox.
Every profile has failed with '**Deployment Error: Unknown user permission CanAccessCE**'.

While the nature of such types of deployment errors is more or less clear, it is really tough to figure out what is the difference in configuration between our 'good' sandbox and this 'bad' new one, and the error message is very cryptic, i.e. have no clue what **CE** means at all.

Is there any documentation available with descriptions of user permission names and which system feature they belong to? Or maybe someone has a clue what **CanAccessCE** may refer to? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: CanAccessCE (Access [Conversation Entries](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.232.0.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_conversationentry.htm)) is the permission that gets enabled when Messaging is enabled in your org. Once you enable "Messaging" in your target org, you can enable the permission "Access to the conversation " for the system admin profile and try deployment. Let me know how it goes. Thanks

Comment: More on enabling the Access Conversation Entries user permission on https://www.infallibletechie.com/2021/05/access-conversation-entries-salesforce.html

Comment: Thanks a lot @Swetha, that was it. Please post this as a separate answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: Happy to know! I've posted this as an answer so it can help other too in future. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CanAccessCE here means 'Access Conversation Entries' permission. It gets enabled when Messaging is turned on in your org.

As per [doc](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_api_objects.htm&type=5&release=232)

> To use the [ConversationEntry](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.232.0.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_conversationentry.htm) object for Chat, you need to enable the new "Access Conversation Entries" user permission.

So to fix the error, once Messaging is enabled in the target environment, you can enable the permission "Access to the conversation " for the system admin profile and proceed with deployment.